# Rendering HTML with embedded javascript in the server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Assume we have an html file that contains DOM manipulation scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let el = document.createElement('div');
            let text = document.createTextNode('Hello World!');
            el.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(el);
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

When this file is sent to the browser, it gets rendered as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let el = document.createElement('div');
            let text = document.createTextNode('Hello World!');
            el.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(el);
        </script> 
        <div>Hello World!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Assuming the source html is sent to an agent other than the browser, we want the rendered html to appear to this agent. Obviously the agent does not contain a javascript interpreter to render the DOM operations. So we need the server to render the javascript in the script tag before sending it to the agent. What is the tool that we can use in nodejs to render the html before sending them to the agent?

Comment: are you asking for a server-side rendering techniques or libraries that support it (like React) or npm package that would take javascript as input and produce dom string as an output?

Comment: Yes, i am asking for a package "or if there is a built-in node functionality" that takes the html that contains scripts that manipulate the DOM and executes those script to produce a rendered html with the manipulated DOM.

Comment: you can send the literal data from the file over.. read up on [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

Comment: I see you use the `node.js` tag meaning you should be able to *read* files(see [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)).. by "send the literal data from the file over" I mean to read the file and send the data you get with an http server

Comment: @TheBombSquad But the file is only rendered in an environment which contains a javascript interpreter "e.g.: the browser". Assume we are using another client other than the browser, like postman, which does not process the response that contains javascript and renders the html elements. So we need some tool that processes the scripts in the html on the server before sending it to the client.

Comment: the browser didn't delete your script tag.. that is definitely html that would run when the browser parses the data it requested

Comment: @TheBombSquad The browser didn't delete the script tag, but it was executed once so I didn't bother to add it again "though I will edit the question to include it". When the script tag got executed the div was added in the rendered html. This process only happens in the browser since there is a js interpreter in the browser. How can we do the same process in the server before sending the data to a client that does not have a js interpreter?